# How to change theme colours from colour code in API globally in react app

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, themes, tailwind-css, mern

I am using react JS with tailwind CSS and i want to change my all components labels and background colours according to the colours that i get from API response, so want to know different approaches and what is the best approach do handle this kind of things
I google that question i found that i need to use **document.documentElement.style.setProperty("colour-var",API response colour)** is this best way or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save API response colour in global state (redux or context), and you can use it in components you want

```
const Component = () => {
    const color = useSelector(state => state.color)
    return <label style={{ background: color }}/>
}
```

Comment: but my question is there are multiple labels and multiple background so i need to add every where ? is there any global solution something like where i change it will change entire react app ?

Comment: oh, if you dont like to add style to every component so i think setProperty css variable is the best way @VasuRangpariya

Comment: but changing with reference to document it is heavy for the performance so any other alternative that can help ?

Comment: dont care too much about performance, i think both is totally fine

Comment: @VasuRangpariya how did you fix this?